# How should I use interaction variables to compare two logistic regressions?

Tags: regression, logistic, multivariate-analysis, interaction

I am working on creating a predictive model using logistic regressions. I am hoping to compare two different populations, using the same set of variables but different data sets with different sample sizes. My goal is to determine if the variables affect the outcome differently to a statistical degree. My analysis is about political socialization of two different populations, so I want to try to determine if xx population is socialized differently than yy population to a statistically significant degree. The two logistic models look different, but I am trying to give a more analytical answer than just "they look different".

I have considered using interaction variables, but for certain models there are a significant number of variables, so that may get out of hand. Could I accomplish this by running individual regressions with each variable to test the interaction?

i.e. DV = B0 + B1*x + B2*w + B3*x*W (x being each unique variable, w being the dummy variable)
And, in theory, if the B3 is statistically significant then the effects of the dummy variable are significant and there is a difference between the populations?

Comment: You end up having to fit more parameters this way than if you did it all in one regression. Each separate regression will have its own intercept.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming 'x' being binomial, consider fitting the Loglinear

```
> dv<- sample(c(0,1), 50, replace = T)
> x<- sample(c(0:1), 50, replace = T)
> w<- sample(c(0:1), 50, replace = T)
> data<- as.data.frame(cbind(w, x, dv))
> data$w<- as.factor(data$w)
> data$x<- as.factor(data$x)
> data$dv<- as.factor(data$dv)
> str(data)
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ w : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ x : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ dv: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 ...
> newdata<- table(data)
> ftable(newdata, row.vars = c('w', 'x'))
    dv 0 1
w x       
0 0    9 5
  1    5 5
1 0    4 8
  1    5 9
> datadf <- as.data.frame(as.table(newdata))
> datadf
  w x dv Freq
1 0 0  0    9
2 1 0  0    4
3 0 1  0    5
4 1 1  0    5
5 0 0  1    5
6 1 0  1    8
7 0 1  1    5
8 1 1  1    9
> mod <- glm(Freq ~ w*dv+ x*dv+ w*x*dv, data = datadf, family = poisson)
> summary(mod)

Call:
glm(formula = Freq ~ w * dv + x * dv + w * x * dv, family = poisson, 
    data = datadf)

Deviance Residuals: 
[1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   2.1972     0.3333   6.592 4.35e-11 ***
w1           -0.8109     0.6009  -1.349    0.177    
dv1          -0.5878     0.5578  -1.054    0.292    
x1           -0.5878     0.5578  -1.054    0.292    
w1:dv1        1.2809     0.8283   1.546    0.122    
dv1:x1        0.5878     0.8433   0.697    0.486    
w1:x1         0.8109     0.8724   0.930    0.353    
w1:dv1:x1    -0.6931     1.1820  -0.586    0.558    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 4.5809e+00  on 7  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 4.4409e-16  on 0  degrees of freedom
AIC: 45.234

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3

> deviance(mod)
[1] 4.440892e-16
> cbind(mod$data, fitted(mod))
  w x dv Freq fitted(mod)
1 0 0  0    9           9
2 1 0  0    4           4
3 0 1  0    5           5
4 1 1  0    5           5
5 0 0  1    5           5
6 1 0  1    8           8
7 0 1  1    5           5
8 1 1  1    9           9
> exp(coef(mod)["w1:dv1:x1"])
w1:dv1:x1 
      0.5 
> exp(confint(mod, parm = c("w1:dv1", 
+                           "w1:x1", 
+                           "w1:dv1:x1")))
Waiting for profiling to be done...
              2.5 %    97.5 %
w1:dv1    0.7441019 20.073855
w1:x1     0.4123005 13.368695
w1:dv1:x1 0.0472905  5.060904
```